# What is the most efficient algorithm of determining all the possible sums of some numbers

Tags: algorithm

We have some set of numbers A = {X1, X2, ... , Xn} and what is the most efficient algorithm to determine all possible sums of the elements of A set? It can be few algorithms with similar efficiency. I rather don't want them to use very sophisticated libraries nor math of that kind.

I'd prefer a solution in pseudocode, Java or C++

PS. When I say efficient, I mean common efficiency of the algorithm of course, not some efficiency out of style of executing the algorithm.

Comment: Google "permutations and combinations".

Comment: The most efficient algorithm is still going to have exponential complexity, because just listing the output will take exponential time, regardless of how you actually *compute* the sums.

Comment: If you investigated the problem a bit, you would quickly see that in the general case any algorithm will take at least exponential time (O (2^n)) and an actual O (2^n) algorithm is trivial, while for special cases the performance is incredibly data dependent, so a "best" algorithm doesn't exist.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some considerations before designing an algorithm.I will start by making some assumptions about the range of the elements in set and size of the set.

First of all lets say the numbers are **A = { X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn }** and they are in the range ***Min <= Xi <= Max***. By this premise, maximum total possible sum will be **SUM = X1 + X2 + C3 + ... + Xn**.

In that case I would start with an array **possibleSums** of size SUM + 1. The array denotes whether a particular sum is possible or not by 0 or 1 respectively. So if lets say 14 is possible from the given set then possibleSums[ 14 ] would have value 1 while if lets say 87 is not possible as a sum from any subset then possibleSums[ 87 ] would be 0. As 0 is always possible by selecting an empty subset so I would start with initialising **possibleSums[ 0 ] = 1**.

After that I iterate through each element **Xi** of the array and for each **possibleSums[ i ] == 1**, I will set **possibleSums[ i + Xi ] = 1**. This is clear because if lets say 13 is possible from the previous elements then by adding the next element 3 , 15 will also be possible.

Below is the code in C++ :

```
// Sum  = X1 + X2 + X3 + ... Xn

bool possibleSums[ Sum + 1 ];

void findAllPossibleSums( int X[ N ] )
{
  // Because in an empty subset sum is 0
  possibleSums[ 0 ] = true;

  for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  {
    /* Now minimum start sum when X[ i ] is included will be X[ i ] and of course maximum sum will be SUM
    */
    for( int j = SUM; j >= X[ i ]; j-- )
    {
      // If sum = j - X[ i ] is possible then sum j is also possible
      if( possibleSums[ j - X[ i ] ] )
      {
       possibleSums[ j ] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  for( int i = 0; i < SUM; i++ )
  {
    // Print the possible sums or whatever you want
    if( possibleSums[ i ] )
      cout << i <<"\n"; 
  }
}
```

The complexity of the above algorithm in worst case is :

**O( Max * n * n )** in time

**O( Max * n )** in space

However space complexity can be reduced by using **(Max * n)** bits for storing possibleSums instead of an array.

Lets analyse the complexity for some cases ( assuming possibleSums is implemented using bits):

For Max  = 100 and n = 10^ 6, it is reaching 10^10 computations for time which is huge.

Another approach to solve this problem would have been to brute force in which I call a recursive method for an index i and inside that since there are two possibilities (to add a number or to leave it), I once added and called the recursion and then second time I called the recursion without adding it. This has the complexity of **O( 2^n )** in time.

The problem is actually a variation of famous [Subset Sum Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which lies in a class of [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problems. Please refer to the wiki link to refer to some special cases which can be solved by pseudo polynomial time algorithms. It may be possible that either the above explained case or some other special case may be applicable to your use.